# Cannot get rid of empty elements in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, null, string

Spent hours reading, researching, and couldn't figure it out, here's my code:

```
    <?php
        $userid = "";
        $accessToken = "";

        function fetchData($url){
             $ch = curl_init();
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
             $result = curl_exec($ch);
             curl_close($ch); 
             return $result;
        }
        $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count=-1");
        $result = json_decode($result);
    ?>

<?php foreach ($result->data as $post):{
        if (stripos($post->caption->text,'egypt') !== false) {
        unset($post);
        $post = (str_split($post->caption->text)); 
        $post = (array_filter($post));
        }
    }
    ?>

<img src="<?= $post->images->low_resolution->url?>" />
<?= $post->caption->text ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

As you can see I am trying to eliminate the responses with "egypt" mentioned in them, I was successfully able to do that by using unset. However I am still getting empty elements, even when using array_filter. The HTML looks like this: `<img src="" />` (as you could imagine) for the Egypt photos.

This is what I am not understanding:

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post):
{
        if (stripos($post->caption->text,'egypt') !== false) {
        }
        else{
        unset($post);
        $posta = (str_split($post->caption->text)); 
        $posta = (array_filter($post));
        $posta = array_filter($posta, 'strlen' );
    }
}
?>    
<img src="<?= $post->images->low_resolution->url?>" /><br>
<?= $post->caption->text ?><br><br>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Gives me the results I want (only egypt photos and descriptions), however it also gives me a PHP error for each: `Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given' and`Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given` isn't array_filter supposed to remove the null values? I would just like to replace the errors with nothing.

Comment: May I suggest that you add a dump of the `$post` object? We cannot _guess_ what that URL replies...

Comment: Also I have the impression that you somehow mix object and array types here...

Comment: you're unsetting post, and then immediately re-assigning values, that means your $post variable will exist, also your array_filter should go outside your foreach() loop

Comment: Would you mind helping me along? It's been around decade since I touched PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing your loop to something like the following:

Only print out when 'egypt' isn't found.

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post){
    if (stripos($post->caption->text,'egypt') === false) {
      $post = (str_split($post->caption->text));?> 
      <img src="<?= $post->images->low_resolution->url?>" />
      <?= $post->caption->text ?>
<?php
    }
    else{
       unset $post;
    }
?>
```

Alternatively you could first clean up your array in one loop, and afterwards print your entries in another loop. This might make it easier to add extra 'filters' later.

```
<?php
    //edit --- typos clean_aray = array(); 
    $clean_array = array();
    foreach ($result->data as $post){
      if (stripos($post->caption->text,'egypt') === false) {
        $clean_array[] = $post;
      }
    }
    foreach ($clean_array as $post){
      $post = (str_split($post->caption->text));?> 
      <img src="<?= $post->images->low_resolution->url?>" />
      <?= $post->caption->text ?>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I am not making much progress using your suggestions, I am real rusty, I am getting null values for everything using your advice and code snippets.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing with the str_split() call. In that position it will overwrite $post with an array containing $post->caption->text split into characters. I assumed this part of your code was working as you indicated in your question. Where is $result->data coming from? you may need to access the variables differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter with a callback function like strlen, this will remove NULL, empty strings, and FALSE and by false I mean explicitly being FALSE and not 0

```
$result = array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );
```